# ExtJS 3.4 Get values of displatField of combo

Tags: extjs, combobox

i have 'n' fieldsets with same id. Each fieldset has some 4 combos (with itemId, displayField and valueField properties). I need to get the displayField values of all the combos in each fieldset. i tried the following,

```
var fieldSets = Ext.query('#fieldsetid');
for (i = 0, maxi = fieldSets.length; i < fieldSets.length; i ++) {
  var form = new Ext.form.BasicForm(fieldSets[i].parentNode);
  var values = form.getValues(); //This line returns valueField value
}
```

With above code i can get the value of valueField of the combo. How can i get the displayText of the combo? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got myself.. get the valueFields from above code in the question. Using it iterate the appropiate store to get the displayLabel as

```
for (var key in values) {
   var keyValue = values[key];
   store.each(function(record) {
     if (record.get(your valueField) == keyValue) {
       values[key] = record.get( your display name);
     }
   });
}
```